# Benford's Law with more than 1 leading digit

Tags: statistics, algorithms, python

I am bit confused on the algorithm of Benford's Law using more than the first leading digit.

I have read a [thesis](http://dspace.library.uvic.ca:8080/bitstream/handle/1828/3031/Thesis.pdf?sequence=1) here that states the law for leading 2 digits is:

$\log_{10} \left( 1 + {\small\dfrac 1 {10d_1 \! + d_2}} \right)$
where $d = d_1 d_2$ and $d$ is within the bounds of 10 to 99.

Would that not be equivalent to the original formula of:

$\log_{10} \left( 1 + {\small\dfrac 1 d} \right)$
where $d$ is within the bounds of 10 to 99.

Is that correct? I have tried googling for a good night, but do not seem to be able to find a formula which applies to leading digits > 1.

Appreciate any help, below is the sample code I have used to generate the results in Python.

```
expected = [log10(1+1/d) for d in range(1,10)]
expected2 = [log10(1+1/(10 *d1+d2)) for d1 in range(1,10)
                                    for d2 in range(0,10)]
expected22 = [log10(1+1/(d1)) for d1 in range(10,100)]

print(expected22,expected2)
```

Comment: Please learn MathJax http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, under Benford’s law
the expected frequency of a specific leading pair of digits
$ d_1d_2 $
$\big( = 10d_1 \! + d_2 = d $,
       with $ d \in \{10,11,12,\ldots,99\} ~\big) $
is just as your program calculated.

\begin{align}
 P ( \text  {first two digits are} ~ d_1 d_2        )
 & = P (  \text {first two digits are} ~ 10d_1 \! + d_2 ) \\[1ex]
 & = P (   \text{first two digits are} ~ d              )  \\[1ex]
 & =   \log_{10} \left( 1 + {1 \over d}\right)
\end{align}

Agreeing with your implicit conjecture,
this holds in general for $n$ leading digits
where $d = d_1 d_2 d_3 ... d_n$
with  $d_1 \in \{ 1,2,3,...,9 \}$,
as gathered from
[*An Introduction to Benford's Law, Chapter 1*,
 Princeton University Press](http://press.princeton.edu/chapters/s10526.pdf)
(no author or year given) — stated
slightly differently here
in a *subtractive* format
that facilitates many applications.

\begin{align}
 P ( \text {first} ~ n ~ \text{digits are} ~ d_1 d_2 d_3 ... d_n )
 & = P (  \text{first}   ~   \text{digits are} ~ d                   ) \\[1ex]
 & = \log_{10} (d{+}1) - \log_{10} d
\kern 7.5em \end{align}

An example for the original question
gives the same result as the familiar format.

\begin{align}
 P ( \text{first} ~ 2 ~ \text{digits are} ~ 76 )
 & = \log_{10} 77 - \log_{10} 76                          \\[1ex]
 & = \log_{10}            {\small { 77  \over 76 }}        \\[1ex]
 & = \log_{10} \left( 1 + { \small{ 1   \over 76 }} \right)
\kern 6em \end{align}

The subtractive format shows its flexibility
on other conceivable questions about the first two digits.

\begin{align}
            P ( \text  {first 2 digits are equal} )
 & =            P (  \text {first are 11}             )
          + P (   \text{first are 22}             )
          + \cdots
          + P (   \text{first are 99}             ) \\[2ex]
 & =            ( \log_{10}  12 - \log_{10} 11 )
          + ( \log_{10}  23 - \log_{10} 22 )        \\[.5ex]
 & \kern 12em + \cdots
          + ( \log_{10} 100 - \log_{10} 99 )        \\
 & = \log_ {10} {\small{ 12 \cdot 23 \cdots 100 \over
                     11 \cdot 22 \cdots  99 }}      \\[1.5ex]
 & = 10.9 \%
\end{align}

\begin{align} \kern 3.5em  \raise 2ex \strut
            P ( \text  {2nd digit is} ~ 6 )
 & =            P (  \text {first are 16}     )
          + P (   \text{first are 26}     )
          + \cdots
          + P (   \text{first are 96}     )      \\[2ex]
 & =            ( \log_{10} 17 - \log_{10} 16 )
          + ( \log_{10} 27 - \log_{10} 26 )      \\[.5ex]
 & \kern 12em + \cdots
          + ( \log_{10} 97 - \log_{10} 96 )      \\
 & = \log_ {10} {\small{ 17 \cdot 27 \cdots 97 \over
                     16 \cdot 26 \cdots 96 }}    \\[1.5ex]
 & = 9.3 \%
\end{align}

This format also telescopes nicely when verified against
the most famous prediction of Benford’s law,
that **1** is the first significant digit
in approximately 30.1% of suitably random numbers.
The first 3 digits are employed this time for variety.

\begin{align} \kern 4.5em
            P ( \text  {first digit is} ~ 1 )
 & =            P (  \text {first are 199}      )
          + P (   \text{first are 198}      )
          + \cdots
          + P  (  \text{first are 100}      ) \\[2ex]
 & =            ( \log_{10} 200 - \log_{10} 199 )
          + ( \log_{10} 199 - \log_{10} 198 ) \\[.5ex]
 & \kern 12em + \cdots
          + ( \log_{10} 101 - \log_{10} 100 ) \\
 & =              \log_{10} 200 - \log_{10} 100    \\[1.5ex]
 & \equiv 30.1 \%
\end{align}

<sub>(The material above was learned while applying Benford’s law
 to Roman numbers in
 [a puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/48351/there-oughta-be-a-law-without-words).)</sub>